# PHP command line run does not show errors

Tags: php

If I run this program on Centos as "php file.php" it shows no output but php -l shows it has errors(; after EOT missing). How do I enable error reporting in this case?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
$str = $_POST['name'];

file_put_contents("out.txt",$str);

print  <<<EOT
<html><body><h1>You've entered $str</h1></body></html>
EOT
```

I've gone through: [How can I get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: If a script has syntax errors, then it cannot be executed; so setting display_errors is meaningless as it can't be executed... you should actually get a parse error displayed when trying to run it

Comment: And your error is a missing `;` after the closing `EOT`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

To override `display_errors=Off` in php.ini, add a `-d` flag to the command line:

```
php -d display_errors=on  script.php
```

Or just edit the ini and turn the flag on.

Comment: Yes now it shows but haven't I already added in the PHP code? I've also tried ini_set('display_errors','On'); in the code.

Comment: @AgA: As Mark explained, php doesn't even run your code. It encounters a parse error and stops.

Comment: So you mean -d display_errors=on   should be used when running on command line?

Comment: @AgA: I'd simply edit the ini file, but if you can't, then yes, adding `-d` is the only option.

Comment: Ttaht option "-d display_errors=on" Does not work for me!

Answer (score 3):

Try to set error_reporting to E_ALL instead of -1, this did the trick for me.

source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#85096

Answer (score 0):

Execute:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

And set display_startup_errors and display_errors in this file.